# Sybase SQL union of two different tables

Tags: sql, sybase, union

Is it possible to make a union from two tables with different number of columns, values and column types in Sybase SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, as long as the columns from the top and bottom part of the union can be converted to the same type.  For example:

```
select  intColumn as col1
,       charColumn as col2
,       decimalColumn as col3
from    Table1
union all
select  null
,       'Halelujah'
,       doubleColumn
from    Table2
```

Comment: So, there isn't a way to make the union with different column types. We have to convert them to the same type right?

Comment: @aF: Yeah, the column type or count cannot vary by row.  However, if you start with different tables, you can transform them into similar shape, like the example does.